# How i can create windows instance in eucalyptus?

Tags: windows, cloud, instance, kvm, eucalyptus

I Installed the cloud-box Eucalyptus and now i want to create windows instance

I successfully done this steps from this [link](http://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/3.4/shared/images_win.html):
1-Install Base Windows OS
2-Install Eucalyptus Windows Integration
3-Configure Active Directory
4-Configure Remote Desktop
5-Run Sysprep
now in step 6:
http://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/3.4/shared/images_vmw_win_convert.html
my questions:

1-the file with this address: ~/.euca/eucarc doesn't not exist.

2-for the next steps I wonder why the img file from the past steps doesn't required?

3-what is vm_image_file and image_bucket ?

4-can anyone explain me more the last two steps?

5-is there any video to show this steps from start to end? because the docs is too hard to follow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This section is for converting a VMDK into an image.  This is important with regards to if you created the Windows image on VMware ESX/ESXi.

This is a bug in our documentation since this is under the subsection - [Create a Windows Image (KVM)](https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/3.4/index.html#shared/images_win.html)

If however you are creating the Windows image on VMware ESX/ESXi, here are the answers to your questions:

> 1-the file with this address: ~/.euca/eucarc doesn't not exist.

This refers to the credentials of the user that will be used to bundle, upload and register the image.  Please refer to [Eucalyptus 3.4 User Guide - Get User Credentials for additional information.](https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/3.4/index.html#user-guide/get_creds.html)  In addition, if the [a user from the 'eucalyptus' account](https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/3.4/index.html#admin-guide/access_special_ids.html) is not being used, please make sure the appropriate [IAM policy](https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/3.4/index.html#admin-guide/access_policies.html) is in place for the user to be able to bundle, upload and register images.

> 2-for the next steps I wonder why the img file from the past steps
>   doesn't required?

This is actually a bug in our documentation.  To help here, would you mind raising a Documentation bug in the [Eucalyptus bug system](https://eucalyptus.atlassian.net).

> 4-can anyone explain me more the last two steps?

Regarding to the steps, you can skip the ["Convert the VMDK to an Image"](https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/3.4/index.html#shared/images_vmw_win_convert.html) steps - if the Windows image isn't being created on VMWare ESX/ESXi.  Therefore, just go to the ["Add Image to Eucalyptus" step.](https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/3.4/index.html#shared/images_win_add.html)

> 5-is there any video to show this steps from start to end? because the
>   docs is too hard to follow.

As mentioned earlier, step 6 - ['Convert the VMDK to an Image'](https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/3.4/index.html#shared/images_vmw_win_convert.html) - can be skipped if the Windows image is not being built on VMware ESX/ESXi.  Therefore, just skip to step 7 - ['Add Image to Eucalyptus'](https://www.eucalyptus.com/docs/eucalyptus/3.4/index.html#shared/images_win_add.html).

Please let us know if there are any question questions.  Hope this helps.

Cheers!